# SSL installed but not Enabled

Tags: ssl, vps, apache2

I have a VPS CentOS and an ssl certificate installed so I can access my website using https with no issues. I'm using PHP/Apache

when I run a test in this url:  [UpGuard](https://app.upguard.com/webscan) [Fail SSL Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EobL.png) I see Fail in front of **SSL Enabled**
SSL is a standard encryption method while browsing websites (see capture) any idea why I get that error?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Run the command

a2enmod ssl

This will enable ssl module for apache2

Comment: I got : bash: a2enmod: command not found

Comment: sorry. It was command for ubuntu

Comment: Can you access your website with https ?

Comment: yes as I montioned that and I have CentOS

Comment: So any command for CentOS please?

Comment: I do not know. If you can access https then ssl is enabled. Make sure you can access https from outside. Allow 443 port in firewall